# .Net - Pushing logs from web application to Docker container running Fluentd

Tags: c#, .net, docker, nlog, fluentd

I want to push .net web application logs to the fluentd image running on Docker container. For this task I installed Docker Toolbox and I ran fluentd image on Docker.

Firstly I tried sending text to the container via telnet and container received those messages and printed on command line.

For sending logs from web application, I tried the method described here (using Nlog.Targets.Fluentd package) https://groups.google.com/d/msg/fluentd/bjf6V0E8oAQ/cTBlxXMbzkAJ .
Connection details like host, port, tag is same as the ones I used in telnet, however I couldn't send logs to the container.

Docker image repository name is "fluent" and tag name is "latest". This is how I run fluentd image on docker:

```
docker run -it ip 47001:24224 fluent:latest
```

And this is how I use Nlog.Targets.Fluentd methods:

```
using (var fluentdTarget = new NLog.Targets.Fluentd())
{
    fluentdTarget.Layout = new NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout("${longdate}|${level}|${callsite}|${logger}|${message}");
    fluentdTarget.Host = "192.168.99.100"; // IP of the docker
    fluentdTarget.Port = 47001; // mapped port number on host
    fluentdTarget.Tag = "fluent:latest"; 
    config.AddTarget("fluentd", fluentdTarget);
    config.LoggingRules.Add(new NLog.Config.LoggingRule("demo", LogLevel.Debug, fluentdTarget));
    var loggerFactory = new LogFactory(config);
    var logger = loggerFactory.GetLogger("demo");
    logger.Info("Hello World!");
}
```

How can I solve this issue? Is there any other way to send logs to the container from web application?